# get list of all dependencies of Spring Initializr, using curl

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In the [official doc](https://docs.spring.io/initializr/docs/current/reference/html/#command-line), it tells how to use `curl` to create a spring project.

eg,

```
curl https://start.spring.io/starter.zip -d dependencies=web,devtools \
     -d bootVersion=2.1.9.RELEASE -o my-project.zip
```

My question is, how can I use `curl` to get the list of all dependencies?

the output should be look like something below

```
# output of `curl ...` to get all dependencies of Spring Initializr
...
web
devtools
...
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's too late and you don't need anymore, but can be helpful to the others...

There is a url that's retrieve relevant info, like version, options and dependencies.

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/json' https://start.spring.io
```

If you want to filter only the names of dependencies, with [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) help, you can request using this command:

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/json' https://start.spring.io | jq '.dependencies.values[].values[].id'
```

The result is something like this:

```
"devtools"
"lombok"
"configuration-processor"
"web"
"webflux"
"data-rest"
"session"
"data-rest-explorer"
"data-rest-hal"
...
```